# li ordering one after another

Tags: html, css

I do not understand why the code below is ordered like the one in the picture.

Each "li" group should order one after another, so the next li should locate below the processor li.

```
<li id="2" class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
```

Groups should not order like this!

[image: Groups should not order like this!]

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please add: `.option { display: inline-block; }` and avoid using the same id multiple times in the same page.

Comment: @emmanuel thank you very much. it worked! and about the id, it is just an example, it is generated automatically from the user id and it is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbq2481x/1/).

Something like this

**HTML**

```
<li class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li>
<li class="option">
  <img class="profile_image" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
  <span class="name" style="padding-left:42px;">
    euglen laknori
  </span>
  <br/>
  euglen.laknori
</li> ...... // other lis
```

**CSS**

```
.option{
  clear: right;
}
```

**Caution:**
Avoid using ids unless it is important. And always avoid same ids in one html page.

Comment: Find my answer helpful? Then please mark it correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple clear on your **li** can fix this. Please don't put your CSS inline and never use numbers as id's.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fpxmk72/)

HTML:

```
<li id="2" class="option">
    <img class="profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
    <span class="name"> euglen laknori </span>
    <br/>
    euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
    <img class="profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
    <span class="name"> euglen laknori </span>
    <br/>
    euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
    <img class="profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
    <span class="name"> euglen laknori </span>
    <br/>
    euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
    <img class="profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
    <span class="name"> euglen laknori </span>
    <br/>
    euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
    <img class="profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
    <span class="name"> euglen laknori </span>
    <br/>
    euglen.laknori
</li>
<li id="2" class="option">
    <img class="profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot"/>
    <span class="name"> euglen laknori </span>
    <br/>
    euglen.laknori
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    clear: both;
}
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
span {
    padding-left:42px;
}
```

Comment: @zeeks No problem! Let me know if this fixes everything or if you need some changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use clear fix for floating elements:

HTML code:

```
<li class="option">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <img class="left profile_image" src="http://www.emperor-penguin.com/penguin-chick.jpg" alt="prov kot" />
        <span class="name">
            euglen laknori
        </span>
        <br/> euglen.laknori
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    font-size: 0px;

    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Demo itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/zrhafhLe/

You had to create a container which will clear after itself float blocks.
More about [clear fix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

P.S.: multiple `id`s isn't good and inline styles are very bad, use classes and CSS stylesheet instead.

Comment: @zeeks you're welcome! :) Is `kot` means 'cat'? Or it's something else?